# XMLHTTPRequest POST getting stuck

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to POST to a google maps service. If you click on the URL you will see the JSON response that I am expecting to get

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Exeter&destination=Deal&region=uk&mode=driving"
xhr.open('POST', url, true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    // do something to response
    alert(this.responseText)
}
```

However, this code gets stops after `xhr.onload = function()`. So I never get the response back. Is there an error in my code?

Comment: You forgot to send the request....

Comment: What environment are you running this JS in where `XMLHttpRequest` is something you have to `require` but `alert` is just available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to send the request.

```
xhr.send("The string of application/x-www-form-urlencoded data you are POSTING goes here");
```

Comment: I was just trying to get back the response back at the moment, as the params are in the url does that matter?

Comment: @JoeBoggs — You are making a POST request and setting a header which says you are going to include a request body that is encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. If you aren't POSTing any data, why are you doing that?

Comment: I realised that was silly, but either way whatever you use the .send seems essential? Its the only way POST or GET works on mine

Comment: Yes, you have to call the `send()` method to send the request.

Answer (score -1):

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Exeter&destination=Deal&region=uk&mode=driving"
xhr.open('POST', url, true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    // do something to response
    alert(this.responseText)
}
xhr.send("data to be send");
```

Try this.